# Retrieving Unicode Text on webrequest

Tags: c#, .net

I send web request with this code :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Display the content.
Response.Write(responseFromServer);
```

But I received wrong data such as &�F� ��S|�"�i�(�

what is the solution?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET and I feel like this is not enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Why do you believe the response is wrong? The characters shown as the response look like a binary value that has been printed as a string. What is the interface specification of the web request being called? What other diagnostics or debugging have you attempted?

Comment: is that work for you ??